# onclick styles the whole li - do not want

Tags: javascript, css

I just came into this project, the code was already written but we noticed a problem. When you click anywhere in the menu it turns the whole thing gold, you can't see any of the links within that section of the menu. You can click on it again and it will return back to the normal state. This only happens in Internet Explorer 9 and Chrome, no problems in Firefox.  The link at the bottom provides an image so you can see the problem.

We have an onclick on the LI for the mobile and IE8 version of the site so they get a nice drop-down menu as well.

When I remove the onclick it takes care of the problem but also prevents the drop-down for the mobile and IE8 users.

Here is the code that I think pertains to this problem:
HTML:

```
<li id="prospective" class="rightborder" onclick="javascript:showElement('prospective-links')">Future Students
<ul id="prospective-links">
<li><a href="/admissions">Undergraduate Admissions</a></li><li><a href="/morelinks">More  Links</a></li></ul>
```

JS

```
function showHide() {
var s=document.getElementById("buttonbar").style;
if ($(window).width() > 949) {
s.display = "block";
document.getElementById("prospective-links").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("current-links").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("academic-links").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("facstaff-links").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("parent-links").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("alumni-links").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("visitor-links").style.display = "block";
$("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
$("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseenter');
$("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseleave');
$.fn.pause=function(a){$(this).stop().animate({dummy:1},a);return this};
function mouseleft(){$("#buttonbar").triggerHandler("mouseleave")}
$(document).ready(function()
{$("#buttonbar").mouseenter(function()      {$(this).stop().pause(160).animate({height:"12.7em"},400,"easeOutQuart")}).mouseleave(function(){$(this).stop().pause(160).animate({height:"2.2em"},400,"easeOutQuart")});});$(function(){$("#accordion").accordion({fillSpace:!0,icons:{header:"accordion-header",headerSelected:"accordion-headerselected"}})});
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||     (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
$("#buttonbar li").bind('touchstart', function(){
console.log("touch started");
});
$("#buttonbar li").bind('touchend', function(){
console.log("touch ended");
});
}

}
else {
/*$("#accordion").accordion({active:false});*/
$("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
$("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseenter');
$("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseleave');
$("#buttonbar li").unbind('touchstart');
$("#buttonbar li").unbind('touchend');

s.display = "none";
document.getElementById("prospective-links").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("current-links").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("academic-links").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("facstaff-links").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("parent-links").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("alumni-links").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("visitor-links").style.display = "none";
/*$("#buttonbar").accordion('destroy');*/
}
} 
else { function showElement(d){ var s=document.getElementById(d).style; 
if (s.display != "block" ) { s.display = "block"; } else { s.display = "none"; } };
```

And the CSS:

```css
#prospective-links li,
#current-links li,
#academic-links li,
#facstaff-links li,
#parent-links li,
#alumni-links li,
#visitor-links li {
   width: 80%;}
prospective-links,
current-links,
academic-links,
facstaff-links,
parent-links,
alumni-links,
visitor-links {
display: none;
}
```

[Menu problem](http://www.cameron.edu/uploads/35/9a/359adc97a384dd7e2350a6aa4ef0af65/menubar.jpg)

Comment: 1) don't use event attributes 2) no need to declare `"javascript:...` 3) missing `#` in the css? 4) why native js and jQuery selectors mixed?

Comment: 1)Not sure what you are talking about.  Can you give me an example?
2)I removed the "javascript:..., but it didn't fix the problem.
3) isn't missing the #, I was having problems getting it to display on here so I removed it.
4)As I said the code was already written.

Comment: You declare `display = "none";` - this seems like the reason for your menu to disappear... or did I misunderstand your question? Event-Attributes should be avoided: `onclick="...` instead you should write: `$("#prospective").on("click",...`. And now that you work on that code again, it seems that this is a good point to refactor the whole code.

Comment: Dude, I started to reindent your code but it turned out to be terrible. I don't think you'll get many answers until you show some more readable code.

Comment: The function being called is `showElement(...)` but the function you have provided here is `showHide()`.  Please add the `showElement` function.

Comment: `else {
function showElement(d){
  var s=document.getElementById(d).style;
  if (s.display != "block" ) { s.display = "block"; } else { s.display = "none"; }
};`  If I change that display="none" to block, it fixes the problem, but then in mobile mode it breaks the menu.

Comment: well, you give to few information. Can you provide a demo page? also add the code to your question please.

Comment: So the `showElement` function is in an else statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give this a shot with the limited info you have provided.

So the section below the "Future Students" in the image is what you are talking about.  You clicked on it and it "turned it gold" like the image.

In actuality what happened was that you clicked on it and it disappeared.  Which according to the function you are calling is the correct behavior.  It was being displayed so now it hides it.  By the way, `showElement` is a horrible name for this function since that is not what it is doing but you inherited it so you may not have control over that.  Something like `toggleElement` would be better.

```
function showElement(d){ 
    var s=document.getElementById(d).style; 
    if (s.display != "block" ) { 
        s.display = "block"; 
    } else { 
        s.display = "none"; 
    } 
}
```

My guess is that in mobile and ie8 these sub-menus start out as hidden so this function does what it is supposed to, i.e. shows the sub-menu on first click and then hides it when clicked again.  Although the function you show here says that should be happening for any window with a width less than 949px `$(window).width() > 949`

That is the best I can do with what we have so far.

Comment: nickles80, you have got it.  I will work on getting a demo set up.  It will likely be next week before I reply.